# Failing Rspec tests at the end of Rails Tutorial ch 9 for unknown reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have searched around and not found anyone experiencing a similar problem, so I would like to post it here.

My tests were all passing until listing 9.40.  I have posted all of my files input between 9.40 and 9.46, although I believe I am following the tutorial precisely.

ERRORS:

```
 1) User_pages delete links as an admin user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
       expected #has_link?("delete", {:href=>"/users/211"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User_pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
     Failure/Error: click_link('delete', match: :first)
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "delete"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 8.95 seconds
84 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45 # User_pages delete links as an admin user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46 # User_pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
```

My files:

https://gist.github.com/ephunit/261670a9fbfe0f3ad471

Much apprecitated for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples that are failing were introduced in Listing 9.42, not Listing 9.40. They should have been inserted as part of the `"index"` example, but you have them inserted as part of the top level `"User Pages"` example.

As a result, the first user is created as an admin user rather than as a regular user, which screws up your results.

This kind of problem is easier to avoid/detect if you faithfully stick to Ruby's indentation conventions of two spaces per indent.